# Probability with replacements

Tags: probability, combinatorics, vectors

> Three components of vectors are chosen randomly from the digits $0$ to $5$ with replacements.
>
> Prove/disprove that $$P(\text{magnitude }=5)=\frac 1{24}$$

Here's my working. Please correct me if wrong.

Suppose $(a,b,c)$ be the scalars which are chosen from $\{0,1,.,5\}$ with replacements.

Thus there are $C(6,1)$ ways for choosing each of $a,b,c$. Therefore, sample space is $\{C(6,1)\}^3$.

To find the number of elementary events, we need to find whole number solutions  to the equation $a^2+b^2+c^2=25$.

They are $\{(0,0,5),(0,5,0),(5,0,0),(3,4,0),(3,0,4),(4,3,0),(4,0,3)\}$ i.e., $7$ solutions.

Thus, probability  is $\frac 7 {6^3}$

Comment: $(0,3,4)$ and $(0,4,3)$ are missing from the possible solutions. This then gives $$P(m=5)=\frac 9{6^3}=\frac 1{24}$$

Comment: My bad! Thanks for pointing it out!